# style checkbox. why :checked is working even the display of the input is set to none?

Tags: css

I want to sytle checkbox and I found something like the following so far by google.

HTML:

```
<div class="chkBoxSquared floatL">
    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="squaredOne" name="check"/>
    <label for="squaredOne"><span>CheckMe</span></label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}
.chkBoxSquared {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;

    margin-right: 120px;

    background: #202020;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
}

.chkBoxSquared label {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 40px;
    width: 120px;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.chkBoxSquared label:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;

    left: 2px;
    top: 2px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;

}

.chkBoxSquared label:hover::before {
    background: #2d5d80;

}

.chkBoxSquared input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {
    background: #55bbff;
}
```

It is working fine, but my question is 
1) Why :checked is working fine even I set the display of that input to none? I can also get the whether the checkbox is checked or not through js. 
2) What change should I make to prevent it from checking the checkbox when I click that "CheckMe" text? I want the checkbox only work when I click on it (deleting the "for" in label breaks functionality of the checkbox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input isn't *actually* visible, its been overlaid with styling of `.chkBoxSquared` then a `:before` pseudo element on the label, which is what you can actually see. To stop it from being visible you'd need to use, as well as on the checkbox:

```
.chkBoxSquared {
    display:none;
}
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/ZxKJ6/3/)

However, because this is hiding the parent element, the label will also be hidden.

This actually isnt a very flexible implementation for a checkbox rewrite, I'm suprised Google would use it, it would be better to move both states to pseudo elements, with the CSS:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/ZxKJ6/5/)

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}
.chkBoxSquared label {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 40px;
    width: 120px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.chkBoxSquared label:after {
    position: absolute;
    content:"";
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    left: 2px;
    top: 2px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
.chkBoxSquared label:before {
    position: absolute;
    content:"";
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    left: 2px;
    top: 2px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    background:#202020;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
}
.chkBoxSquared input[type=checkbox]:disabled + label:before, .chkBoxSquared input[type=checkbox]:disabled + label:after {
    display:none;
}
.chkBoxSquared label:hover::after {
    background: #2d5d80;
}
.chkBoxSquared input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    background: #55bbff;
}
```

**[Then you can simply add `disabled='true'` to the checkbox to hide/show it](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/ZxKJ6/4/).**

Comment: May be I didn't describe my questions very well. for Q1, I am suprised that :checked pseudo is still working when you set one element's display to none. Q2: usually if you want your checkbox works with the text after it, you add "for" with the same name to the one you set to id for the input. what if I don't want my checkbox work with the text after it(CheckMe in my case)? Deleting the "for" does not work in my case.

Comment: Q1- it works because you are actually clicking the label, clicking a label with `for` changes the related checkbox value. Q2 removing `for` would prevent you from being able to use a custom style, due to the answer for Q1. Solution- remove the text of the label, and create a mock label element.